# How get battery temperature with decimal?

Tags: android, android-intent, battery, temperature

How can i get the battery temperature with decimal? Actually i can calculate it with

```
int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
```

But in this way the result will be for example `36 °C`.. I want something that show me `36.4 °C` How can i do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Google says [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_TEMPERATURE) :

> Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: **integer** containing the current battery temperature.

The returned value is an int representing, for example, 27.5 Degrees Celcius as "275" , so it is accurate to a tenth of a centigrade. Simply cast this to a float and divide by 10.

**Using your example:**

```
int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
float tempTwo = ((float) temp) / 10;
```

OR

```
float temp = ((float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0) / 10;
```

You don't need to worry about the 10 as an int since only one operand needs to be a float for the result to be one too.

Comment: something like `float temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0)/10;`?

Comment: exactly. android just uses an int to save some memory since the battery won't reach higher than 4.3 Billion degrees that often.

Comment: seems good. With your solution works.. But for now it's stuck "35.0 °C" .. i try to wait and see if something change

Comment: `Using your example: int returnedValue = 270; float castedValue = ((float) returnedValue) / 10;` have i to write it after `int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);`?

Comment: I don't understand where you have put the intent for the temperature in here `int returnedValue = 270; float castedValue = ((float) returnedValue) / 10;` i missed something

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static String batteryTemperature(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));    
        float  temp   = ((float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0)) / 10;
        return String.valueOf(temp) + "*C";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the only way I know you can get the battery temperature, and is always an int.

According to documentation:

> public static final String EXTRA_TEMPERATURE
>
> Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: **integer** containing the current battery
> temperature.

But you can divide by 10.0f to get one decimal.

float ftemp = temp/10.0f;

Comment: Thanks for the replay.. Is there any way to convert the Integer? This application for example has decimals https://lh4.ggpht.com/yoR8kC9GTLEyKbFFYKohbW1P8z1L00_wYJjKykAIqhhbVMAFxbwiA02s4m9aTSwxBQ=h900-rw

Comment: is possible do something like:  `int i = 56472201;

float e = ((float) i)/1000000.0

double e = i / 1000000.0;` ?

Comment: Do you know if the temperature is always ending with .0°? If it is, you can just change your int to a float like this: temp/10.0f

Comment: in which sense "if the temperature is always ending with .0°?"

Comment: Sorry I thought the app only added the 0 on purpose, but the numbers you're getting can be divided by 10.0f, like this: temp/10.0f to get 1 decimal value